# Editview below Listview lossing focus

Tags: android

I have a fragment with Editview below a listview but when I clicked of the editview and soft keyboard appear the Editview losses fucus. I searched and tried all the answers in Stack Overflow but non worked. Below is fragment XML.

Comment: please show your xml file

Comment: You wrote *Below is fragment xml.* but I can't see it. Where is your fragment.xml ???

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not adding the xml. I was able to sort it out by just adding the below code inside OnCreateView

getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);